# How to draw this net?

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams

I tried to draw this figure but no succeed. I would like to draw fuzzy and BEL model.

I used this code

```
    \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{tikz}
    \usetikzlibrary{positioning,calc,fit}

    \begin{figure*}[!ht]
    \centering 

    \newcommand{\bloc}[2]{
    \begin{scope}[shift={#1}]
    \begin{scope}[every node/.style={circle, draw, minimum size=2em}]  
     \node[circle, draw] [blue](#2-c1){};
     \node[below left=1em of #2-c1][blue](#2-c2){};%to draw a circle inside a box
      \node[below left=1em of #2-c2][blue](#2-c3){};
       \node[below left=1em of #2-c3][blue](#2-c4){};
     \end{scope} 
        \node[above left=1em and 0em of #2-c1][blue](#2-tt){#2};%to label the box by names Thalamus,Sensory Cortex
    \node[draw,fit=(#2-c1) (#2-c2) (#2-c3) (#2-c4) (#2-tt)][red](#2){};%to draw a boxes


    \end{scope}
     }
 \end{figure*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I tried to post the graph but it does not downloaded/attached any idea to do that?

Comment: Please, provide complete small document beginning with `\documentclass{...}` end ending with `\end{document}`, that we can see context of your `\newcommand`. In your `\newommand` you have defined two arguments, but used only second one.

Comment: I tried to upload the fig ,but it is not excepted any idea to post the fig ?

Comment: Hi, I have proived to put `\end{figure*}` and`\end{document}`, with the indications of Zarko.

Comment: Sebastiano do this for you, but question is, if this image really illustrate your problem. As far I see, it hasn't anything common with your code snippet. and code is still not an complete minimal document.

Comment: You're right. Infact with Papeeria there is not any image.

Comment: You define a **\newcommand** named **\bloc** in a **figure*** environment and do not use the command in the code later. I also do not get any output (blank page).

Comment: As @Dr.ManuelKuehner says, you need to actually use the macro you've defined, and use it inside a `tikzpicture`, e.g. `\begin{tikzpicture} \bloc{(0,0)}{Thalamus} \end{tikzpicture}`.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because the OP has simply forgot to use his macro. The code in the macro works perfectly fine.